# Adding facet titles and changing legend title in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wonder how to add facet titles in ggplot2

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut)) + geom_bar() +   facet_grid(color ~ clarity)
```

and change the legend title

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut, fill=cut)) + geom_bar() +   facet_grid(. ~ clarity)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The facets are labeled using the levels of the factor used. So if you simply change the levels , such as

```
levels(diamonds$clarity) <- letters[1:8]
```

those facets will now be labeled using those letters. The legend title matches the label for that aesthetic mapping, which you can set via:

```
+ labs(fill = "Fill legend label")
```

As an extra tidbit, I've noticed that I can set the `x` and `y` axis labels to NULL in `labs` but not the legend titles; for those you use an empty character if you want no title.

*Edit*

Given your clarifications, you can add text outside the plotting area using `grid.text`:

```
print(qplot(1,1),vp = viewport(width = 0.9))
grid.text(unit(0.95,"npc"),0.5,label = "Right label", rot = 270)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. + labs(fill = "Fill legend label") works. For facet title I want to add some title not label for categories.

Comment: @MYaseen208 In that case I have no idea what you mean. In ggplot2 each facet has a strip at the top (or side) that acts as a sort of title for that facet. Did you mean you want to annotate each facet with some text? In that case, put the text in a data frame and add it as a layer with `geom_text`.

Comment: Thanks for sparing time and helping me. In my first code, color has seven levels (D, E, F, G, H, I, J) and these levels are displayed on the right side. Besides that I also want to put some facet title like "Color of Diamond" in the same way as xlab. Sorry I was not able to explain very well.

Comment: @MYaseen208 I think I've answered your question now, I hope. You'll have to tinker with the positioning a little bit though for your particular plot.

Comment: @MYaseen208 It may not. But I think you can make it work if you use the technique referred to in A.9 [here](http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/~leisch/Sweave/Sweave-manual.pdf).

Comment: Is still the solution? I get `Error: could not find the function grid.text`

Comment: @Hendy I should have specified that you need to load **grid** with `library(grid)`.

Comment: Gotcha. The syntax looked similar to ggplot, so I thought it was an option or included there. I have a legend because I grouped faceted bar plots by color. I'd have to move the legend and tweak the position for this to work -- there's not enough room between the axis and legend to insert a label at present.