# ggplot with 4 label and range,

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this code

the result is

How I can add labels to the top and to the right side?
can I change the title of color from "host_is_superhost" to Super Host?
I also want help in cutting the top and the right range to start from number 6, not 2?
Any help, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ddata %>%
  filter(review_scores_cleanliness < 5, review_scores_location < 5) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y=review_scores_rating, x=number_of_reviews, color=host_is_superhost)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(review_scores_cleanliness ~ review_scores_location) + 
  labs(y = "Review Scores Rating", x = "Number of Reviews", color = "Super Host")
```

This code will do most of what you want. The only aspect that is not easy is adding titles on the top and right sides of the plot. [This answer provides a hack to do so.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36123318/5221626)